Flow of data in GUI apps
When syncing data between different levels in Swing (or any GUI project, for that matter), what is the right flow of data in that sync chain? Like so?
DB -> Model -> UI
I was trying to implement a different flow whereby DB data is synced with the UI model
The advantage is you can implement some things on a higher level of abstraction. For instance, imagine you want to flip the value of each boolean cell and move to the next row when the Space key is pressed. It may be quite convenient. You can implement it abstractly at the model level without knowing any DB identifiers. Then you may listen to those model changes and update the persisted data accordingly
However, what if the DB rejects the data? Then the model (and the UI) will be out of sync with the actual persisted data
So I wonder if the order I specified above the only right order that I should follow in apps I collaborate on (even at the cost of making certain things more difficult to implement, or at the cost of copy and paste)?
Implementation-specific note. The UI is synced with model data automatically in Swing. It seems I can't change the model (which I can perform without knowing any DB identifiers), try to persist it and only then, if everything's fine, display the data in the GUI. That is, this is not possible in Swing — it seems
Model -> DB -> UI

I do believe there's the right way and the wrong way so don't consider this question opinion-based


However, what if the DB rejects the data? Then the model (and the UI) will be out of sync with the actual persisted data

Most systems which have this kind of model layer do the validation in the models, so this can't happen. If the data is valid in the models, it will commit to the DB.
If you additionally do validation in the DB, you have effectively two layers of "model" because the DB is modelling business logic as well.
But there's nothing wrong with the DB being out of sync with the persisted data! You have the model represent what's on the UI, including any invalid input. You may then highlight invalid fields in the UI, and so on. If you want to get the model back to the DB state, this is then a UI action called something like "reset form". That reloads the models from the DB, flowing through to the UI.
